# Swift custom protocol which calls more than one function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delegates, protocols

I have a login view controller. Once the login is done, it dismisses itself and calls a function in another view controller. And in that function there are four different functions that do different actions. The problem is the protocol calls 4 functions at the same time. So is there a way to call a specific function inside the other function? like;

```
   func mainfunction(){
            funcOne()
            funcThree()
            funcTwo()
            funcOne()
          }
```

So instead of calling all, I want to call one. And mainFunction is a part of protocol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add the separate functions in the protocol declaration, you will be able to call them individually if they exist.

The protocol serves as a contract of what should be implemented. It gives the compiler and developers a way of knowing what is supposed to be available. It's very similar to the concept of declaring functions ahead of time in a C header file. The functions are not available until you or someone else implements them.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend your protocol. Instead of having one `mainFunction`, the protocol would have all four.

```
@protocol YourProtocol {

    func funcOne()
    func funcTwo()
    func funcThree()
    func funcFour()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there is that kind of a problem. In Login view controller for example; self.delegate.funcOne() and self.delegate.funcTwo() calls these before dismissing itself. how login controller can know that who called itself and which of these functions it should call... otherwise, it still calls both of them at the same time